# According to Catholicism what is meant by living in a state of obstinate sin?

Tags: catholicism, sin

About a week a go I heard about something called obstinate sin. What is obstinate sin? Is it the same as not listening to God?

According to Catholicism what is meant by living in a state of obstinate sin?

Answer (score 2):

**Obstinacy in sin** is one of six sins against the Holy Spirit and can only be absolved by a priest when the [obstinacy in sin stops](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50741/25495) and the sinner is truly ready to amend his way of obstinacy.

[What Are The Sins Against The Holy Spirit?](http://www.stjw.ca/adults/frequently-asked-questions/god-the-holy-spirit/what-are-the-sins-against-the-holy-spiritij/)

> 1) Despair,
>    "By despair, we cease to hope for our personal salvation from God, for help in attaining it or for the forgiveness of our sins.  Despair is contrary to God's goodness, to his justice - for the Lord is faithful to his promises and to his mercy." (CCC  # 2091)
>
> (2) Presumption of God's mercy,
>    "There are two kinds of presumption. Either we presume upon our own capacities, (hoping to be able to save ourselves without help from God), or we presumes upon God's almighty power or His mercy (hoping to obtain his forgiveness without conversion and glory without merit)." (C.C.C. # 2092)
>
> (3) Watering down the known truth
>    To water down the known truth means to weaken it by making all religious truths subjective (claiming that there is no objective truth), to attack it by word or argument, to resist it, to contradict it, or even to oppose the known truth or to challenge it as false.
>
> (4) Envy the spiritual good of another
>    Regarding the gifts of the Holy Spirit, the First Letter of Paul to the Corinthians states, "All these are activated by one and the same Spirit, who allots to each one individually as the Spirit chooses."  To envy the spiritual good of another is to question the Divine judgment of the Holy Spirit in His distribution of spiritual gifts.  It is to be jealous of another person who has a gift different than one's own gift.  Through envy, one rejects the gift that they have received from the Holy Spirit, determining in their own minds that the gift they have received is not good enough for them and they want someone else's gift.
>
> (5) **Obstinacy in sin**
>    To be "obstinate" means to resist the sanctifying power of the Holy Spirit, to be stubborn, to persist in sin, to be unyielding.
>
> (6) Final impenitence
>    "Impenitence" means to be uncontrite, unrepentant, hardened, unconverted, to be without regret, shame or remorse.

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the sins against the Holy Spirit:

- Despair (believing that one's evil is beyond God's forgiveness);
- Presumption (glory without merit, that is, hope of salvation without
  keeping the Commandments, or expectation of pardon for sin without
  repentance)
- Envying the goodness of another (sadness or repining at
  another's growth in virtue and perfection);
- **Obstinacy in sin** (willful
  persisting in wickedness, and running on from sin to sin, after
  sufficient instructions and admonition);
- Final impenitence (to die
  without either confession or contrition for our sins);
- Impugning the
  known truth (to argue against known points of faith, and this
  includes misrepresenting parts or all of the Christian faith to make
  it seem undesirable). [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_sin)