# How do various denominations interpret Jesus’ declaration of “Blasphemy Against the Holy Spirit” as an unforgivable sin

Tags: exegesis, pneumatology, comparative-christianity, blasphemy, unforgivable-sin

A few times questions about “Blasphemy Against the Holy Spirit” have been asked on this site and then closed as either “off topic” since they are interpretative per denomination, or closed as “duplicate” which then links to a different closed question.

To try to remedy this, since I believe it’s an important topic to discuss, I am curious how various denominations interpret this “unforgivable sin”.

> How is “Blasphemy against the Holy Spirit” interpreted by various denominations?

> What are some of the key disagreements between various denominations on this topic?

> What do they [an aforementioned denomination] use as supporting evidence for their interpretations?

An answer of any specific denomination is helpful, you (of course) don’t have to answer how each and every denomination interprets this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right forum for holding a "discussion" on this topic.  You might find the following question (and answer) useful: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/41863/how-do-protestants-understand-the-unforgivable-sin?rq=1

Comment: Here is another Stack Exchange link regarding the Catholic view: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34474/according-to-catholic-teaching-what-is-sinning-against-the-holy-spirit?rq=1

Comment: This is not a forum for **discussion**, but rather a question and answer site that are to be supported by facts, links and scholarly work. Please edit your last paragraph accordingly.

Comment: @KenGraham I've removed the section about encouraging discussion; what else is needed to re-open this quesiton?

Answer (score 1):

In the Church of the Reformation (my fellowship), blasphemy against the Holy Spirit is viewed as a rejection of salvation from a place of real understanding of what you are choosing (no deception, no double-mindedness). It is the unpardonable sin because eternal life is not innate but comes from the receiving of Holy Spirit, so to reject Holy Spirit is to reject life itself. And if you don't have life, you don't have salvation.

Consider:

John 3:16

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

Galatians 6:8

> Whoever sows to please their flesh, from the flesh will reap destruction; whoever sows to please the Spirit, from the Spirit will reap eternal life.

Romans 8:1-2

> Therefore, there is now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus, because through Christ Jesus the law of the Spirit who gives life has set you free from the law of sin and death.

John 6:63

> The Spirit gives life; the flesh counts for nothing. The words I have spoken to you—they are full of the Spirit and life.

Comment: I believe this view is fairly widespread, at least among Protestants. It's not even a "sin", so much as it's being offered forgiveness and saying "no, I don't want that".